# Why won't jQuery let me animate the background color of a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I found this animation example on w3schools.com:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
  {
  $("#btn1").click(function(){
    $("#box").animate({height:"300px"});
  });
  $("#btn2").click(function(){
    $("#box").animate({height:"100px"});
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button id="btn1">Animate height</button>
<button id="btn2">Reset height</button>
<div id="box" style="background:#98bf21;height:100px;width:100px;margin:6px;">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**([This can be run here](http://jsfiddle.net/kyo404gk/))**

However if I try to change this to animate the background color instead of the height, it doesn't work.  Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
  {
  $("#btn1").click(function(){
    $("#box").animate({backgroundColor:"#0000ff"});
  });
  $("#btn2").click(function(){
    $("#box").animate({backgroundColor:"#98bf21"});
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button id="btn1">Animate height</button>
<button id="btn2">Reset height</button>
<div id="box" style="background:#98bf21;height:100px;width:100px;margin:6px;">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**([This can be run here](http://jsfiddle.net/uLdfdhqm/))**

This jQuery tutorial (http://jqueryui.com/animate/) makes it seem like this should work, so where am I going wrong?  Thanks!!

Comment: I had the same issue awhile ago...I ended up using [this jQuery plugin](http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/).

Comment: Set up jsFiddle correctly and include the required libraries: http://jsfiddle.net/rx2jzwmj/

Answer (score 3):

jQuery, itself, doesn't provide animation of color values. You need a plugin to do it. There are several, including **but not limited to** jQuery UI. Search for "jQuery color animation" to find your options. Here are the top three as of this writing:

- [jQuery UI](http://api.jqueryui.com/color-animation/)
- [Color animation jQuery plugin](http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/).
- [jquery-color](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color/)

Comment: useful, though the OP is presumably using jquery ui for things other than color animation. **I made this assumption.** IF NOT, this is the best answer.

Comment: @Todd: Yeah, hard to tell. On the one hand, the main snippet given doesn't include jQuery UI. On the other hand, the linked tutorial in the question is for jQuery UI. :-) My guess is like many, many people, they're getting jQuery and jQuery UI confused, which is fair enough.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the jQuery UI plugin in your HTML in order to animate colors:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<!-- Other HTML -->
</head>
```

The stylesheet is optional but you need the JS file. Also, make sure you include the UI module after jQuery itself.

[See an updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uLdfdhqm/2/).

Answer (score 0):

**Small mistake you're making:**

You've got to load jquery ui library in order for this to work. Add this just below your inclusion of main jquery.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```